# How to configure WinRM for azure virtual machine in resource manager portal

Tags: virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, winrm

I have created a VM in azure resource manager portal using powershell. How to configure WinRM in VM for remote access using powershell. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by adding a custom script extension when deploying the VM. An example can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/3c9980dd6baf21e84e48fcc9028ee54b3c0269f6/201-vm-winrm-windows).
To add this to an existing VM, just copy the ConfigureWinRM.ps1, makecert.exe and winrmconf.cmd files from the same [quickstart folder](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/3c9980dd6baf21e84e48fcc9028ee54b3c0269f6/201-vm-winrm-windows) and execute the powershell script.

Comment: If a VM is already created in past, but the WinRM has not been configured, then in that case, is it possible to achieve the same from any client machine by running these scripts?

Comment: yes, you can run the scripts on an existing vm. You can add the custom script extension after the VM is already created.